# Find in string two first words (Regular expression)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have string. It can be in the following format

**Folkestone** Result

**Ascot** (IRE) Result

**Folkestone Last** (IRE) Result

**Winterfall Win** Result

Help create a regular expression to search for words in bold!

```
(.*)(?=\()|Result
```

My version is not quite working correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solution!

```
/^(.*?)(?=\(|Result)/m
```

Alternation inside the lookahead. Use in multiline-mode: *m modifier*

[test at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/rI6kD9), [regex faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)

Comment: Wow that is such a great tool you shared here @Jonny5 ! I was using rubular.com but I will change for refex101 for sure! Thanks